# Is Microsoft Orleans not really made to support legacy applications?

Tags: orleans

After a bunch of googling, I don't really see a good way to have Orleans work with an existing Relation-Database backend.

Every example that I have found for doing this relies on adding columns to deal with concurrency and I haven't really seen any samples of how to use Orleans with, as is the typical example, the northwind database or something.

This leads me to believe that Orleans is not really intended to be used in this way (because if it was I would expect someone somewhere to have create a sample app demonstrating it by now).  Am I missing something?  Has anyone seen a sample project or blog post explaining how  to use, say, an existing EF context with Orleans?  This needs to be done without adding additional columns. I am working with data that is controlled by multiple teams in a mission critical system, so there is no way I will get approval to start adding columns to hundreds of tables.

Comment: Are you asking how you would use an existing database as the state store for your grains? That doesn't really make sense as the contention from the other system would negate a lot of the benfits you get from Orleans. That said you can overwrite the state loading method (or write a state plugin) and do it.... If you just mean how to actually USE a EF Context, you can just do that as normal, nothing special required

Answer (score 0):

As @Milney says, to my knowledge, there is nothing special in Orleans that would prevent you from using a normal EF DbContext, no extra columns required.

If, on the other hand, your issue is that other applications are causing concurrency issues from outside Orleans, then I think you'll need to deal with them as you would in any application (e.g. with optimistic concurrency checks).

But it's possible I'm misunderstanding your use case.